# npm won't start:dev on NestJS application

Tags: npm, nodemon, nestjs

So I created a new `NestJS` application with the CLI. I got `nodemon` installed as a dependency and globally. My `package.json` looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
"format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
"start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
"start:dev": "nodemon",
"start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
```

and my `nodemon.json` looks like this:

```
"watch": ["src"],
"ext": "ts",
"ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
"exec": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts"
```

So very basic setup. But if I try so start the dev server with: `npm start:dev`, I get this error message:

```
Usage: npm < command >

where < command > is one of:

access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
edit, explore, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
whoami

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file: /Users/XXXXX/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.6.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

Did you mean this?
    start
```

My `npmrc` contains some credentials for my github repo from my job !

Comment: Because I could not find myself anything related to this after searching a lot, I created this comment on a somewhat related post https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803280/588003 .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To run a npm script you must call `npm run`. So call `npm run start:dev`.

Comment: @Maxstgt Glad it worked for you. :-) Consider accepting the answer so that others know your problem is solved. Of course, feel free to leave the question open and wait for other answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers