# Nest js: npm run start fails

Tags: nestjs, npm-run

I'm trying to create a Nest js application, but when I follow the steps on their website, the first error I get is 'cannot find ts-node'. So, I installed that. There were a couple more typscript modules I needed to install (typscript and tsconfig-paths I believe) and when I cleared those errors up and run npm run start I got a 'Cannot find node module @nestjs/core'.

Answer (score 2):

**[RELATED UPDATE]**

I'm running Node v12.14.1 and npm v6.13.4 on a MacBook Pro 13", Late 2011, running macOS High Sierra.

For the past few weeks I have been trying (not continuously) to find an issue, where I would try to run Node well known frameworks, namely NestJS and NextJS, without success, in a similar manner than suggested in this post.

After following the "getting started" instructions, whenever I would run `npm run start` (**NestJS**) or `npm run dev`(**NextJS**) , in both cases the app would just die silently, no feedback at all, no error message, no nothing. Just stopped.

Last try was to repeat the same steps on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with exactly the same versions Node v12.14.1 and npm v6.13.4 and everything worked fine.

To wrap up, I don't know the cause, I have a vague idea of having read that there is a know issue with npm and latest version(s) of webpack, but for me what got it working was to use **yarn** instead of **npm** .

`yarn start` (**NestJS**) or `yarn dev`(**NextJS**) did the job.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you are working with typescript you have to install it in order to be able to use the `tsc` command which will transpille your code to javascript.

you also need to install `ts-node` when you want to work with a transpillation on the fly. that's why you need it.

Finally, you missing to install the necessary packages to be able to work with nest which are listed at this url:
 https://docs.nestjs.com/

using the following command: 
`$ npm i --save @nestjs/core @nestjs/common rxjs reflect-metadata`

Actually, you are missing the `@nestjs/core` as well as the `@nestjs/common` packages which are fundamental.

Comment: I think I know what happened. Maybe. In the nest new process a section where it asks whether to use npm or yarn. The first couple of times I used npm and I'm pretty sure it added my node_modules but I was getting the errors I stated above, right? Well I just tried it again but this time I used yarn, which failed. It gave me the error, "failed to execute command: yarn install --silent". Afterwards, I noticed that I didn't have node_modules so I ran npm install on my project folder and was able to run npm run start on my nest project and navigate to localhost:3000. Thoughts.

Comment: When you choose to use npm did you get an error after the process ? Could you try again and see if you have everything in your nodemodules

Comment: The only error I would get from selecting npm is that the git init failed to execute. Which is expected because I don't have git installed.

Comment: And then in your node modules have you all the required packages ?

Comment: Well probably not, I'll check again. It's probably why I was getting errors with ts-node etc. However, the @nestjs/core thing seems odd because I installed it globally.

Comment: The npm i run by the cli should install everything for you as well as the core

Comment: Something else that seems peculiar. So, all the problems I've been having were if I created the project in a VS terminal window, but if I make the project in powershell it works just fine. I'm not sure why.

Comment: what happen when you running npm -v in a visual studio terminal ?

Comment: It gives me the same version as powershell. 6.4.1

Comment: Right? that's what I'm thinking. Maybe I should raise the issue on their github? Either way Thanks for your help. I'll make sure to mark this thread as the answer :)